# Vanish of derivative under suitable coordinate.

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

$(M,g)$ is a compact Riemannian manifold. Let $u$ be a solution of $\Delta u = F(u)$ on $M$.
$$
f:=\frac{|\nabla u|^2}{(\mu\sup u-u)^2}
$$
Assume $x_0\in M$ st $f$ achieves its supremum. Then, why I can assume $\partial_\alpha u =0$ for $\alpha >1$ by choosing suitable orthonormal frame at $x_0$ ?

This question  is from 209 page of Li and Yau's *Estimates of eigenvalues of a compact Riemannian manifold*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I'm misunderstanding, none of your assumptions on $u$ are required. Just choose any orthonormal frame $E_\alpha$ with $E_1 = C \mathrm{grad}(u),$ and you naturally have $$\partial_{E_\alpha} u= \langle\mathrm{grad}(u), E_\alpha\rangle=\frac 1 C\langle E_1, E_\alpha \rangle = \frac 1 C\delta_{1 \alpha}.$$

Comment: I just don't know what assumptions are required, so I add them all.

Comment: Whether it should be $\partial _{E_\alpha} u =\langle grad(u) , E_\alpha \rangle=\frac{\langle E_1,E_\alpha\rangle}{C}=\frac{\delta_{1\alpha}}{C}$ ?

Comment: @lanse7pty: yeah, sorry, that's right.